# Git for Mac fails to launch: "illegal instruction"

Tags: macos, git, github

...I've looked pretty carefully (I believe), and have been unsuccessful at getting an installation of Git for my Mac.

For various reasons, I'm running 10.6.8 of Mac OS X and will not be changing that anytime soon.

I've already gathered and installed the bundle exposed here:

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

The installation instructions are pretty clear, and it's obvious to me that the package installed.  But any attempts to use the git client from the command line result in an "Illegal Instruction" error.

I've sifted pretty carefully through information available here:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

There is another bundle that seems to be available.  It is called "GitHub for Mac 1.7.5, but it appears to require Mac OS X 10.7 or later.

Has anyone else encountered this difficulty? Must I build from source?

I'm a couple of hours of reading and hacking into this effort? Is there something obvious that I've not considered?

Comment: kindly provide the link you downloaded to install

Comment: Here's where I got the bundle: [http://git-scm.com/download/mac] It gives me Git 1.9.0.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, I've had the same exact problem, and what I did is installed an earlier build from here:
https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/

I'm running 10.6.8 and installed the newest build there, 1.8.4.2

SourceForge only has 1.9.0 and 1.8.5.2 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/reviews?source=navbar

Someone on the reviews said they had trouble with both and went back to 1.7. I would try that if 1.8.4.2 doesn't work.

I was able to run the config commands without an illegal instruction error, at least.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I am a new user. If I ask a new question, then it's duplicate, which doesn't help anyone. I tried to add a comment but wasn't allowed. It's sort of a catch-22 when you have 1 reputation. And the question did ask whether other people have encountered the problem.

Comment: Very understandable. But your answer does not help anyone either. I think "_Has anyone else encountered this difficulty?_" not is meant as a "yes" or "mee too" request, but if anyone have encountered the problem and **solved** it.

Comment: @davidkonrad, thanks for the explanation. I edited the post to give more of a solution.

Comment: This was the best solution for me. Although the archive at code.google.com wants to send you to sourceforge, the sourceforge archives do not have copies old enough. I found the Leopard (not Snow Leopard) git package (1.7.5.4) to be the one I needed, still available at https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list

Comment: Also got 'Illegal instruction' whenever trying to call 'git' on an OSX 10.6.8 (uname -a 'Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0') machine.

Can confirm that git-1.8.4.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg (from deprecated https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) works.

Can also confirm that 'git-1.8.5.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg' or newer (from http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/) does not work; they all result in 'Illegal instruction'.

Comment: This still works -- snow leopard server 10.6.8.  This was huge help!

Answer (score 4):

I had this today on Snow Leopard after running the suggested git installer from git-scm. Really horrible. Found that installing Macports using their [old Snow Leopard package](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.0-10.6-SnowLeopard.pkg) and then

```
sudo port install git +svn +doc +bash_completion +gitweb
```

installs git plus its dependencies and git now works fine; version 1.9.3 installed and working on 10.6.8.

Comment: Ran into the same wall. I installed Xcode from my Snow Leopard DVD. Then ran a slightly modified version of the above command 'sudo port install git + svn...' just 'git' as  'git-core' is said to be obsolete. All seems ok. git --version returns 'git version 2.0.1'. Thanks @Polsonby.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and was able to install a working version using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

```
# first uninstall the broken version
# mount the DMG for the broken version using Finder
# "type" this with the tab key! it saves typing and fixes the version number
cd /Volumes/Git\ 2.0.1\ Snow\ Leopard\ Intel\ Universal/
./uninstall.sh
# make bash forget about the uninstalled binary
hash -r
cd

# now install the working version
# assumes you have Homebrew installed
brew install git
git version
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. There are various methods for downloading and installing git - Try macports or homebrew. The thing that finally worked for me was having xcode 3.2.6 installed with the additional command line tools - version 3.2 that comes with the leopard install disk wasn't enough. You can install xcode etc. from the disk and then run software update to upgrade it to 3.2.6.

Answer (score 2):

The latest build for Snow Leopard in the official ***git-osx-installer*** repo is **Git 2.3.5** currently. You can download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/git-2.3.5-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg/download using web browser. This installation works for me on OS X 10.6.8.

Or you can check yourself for a newer version:
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it seems that it does not support the older OS version (mine was 10.6.8). I upgraded to the newest Mac OS 10.9.4 (the installation will take a while), reinstalled the Git software (note that it will ask for xcode to be installed, which I proceeded), and everything works fine from there. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Ref : https://help.github.com/articles/does-github-for-mac-run-on-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard

To quote:

> ### Does GitHub for Mac run on OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?
>
> **No**, GitHub for Mac requires OS X 10.7 (Lion) or higher.
>
> We made this decision because the app relies on a number of
>   technologies which are not available in Mac OS X 10.6 or earlier. We
>   want to provide the best experience possible for the app's users, so
>   we've made the choice to only support 10.7 and above, and not make
>   earlier versions available.

Comment: Original question is talking about Git for Mac not GitHub for Mac.

Comment: @Leigh : which is why I had doubts about my "answer" and additionally left a comment on the question asking for the link to check if it's `Github for Mac` or `Git-1.x.x` package because the question seems like it could go either way. but... i am guessing it's `Git 1.x.x` package due to the `Illegal Instruction` error but waiting on the OP to verify

Comment: So I tried both actually. I have git-1.9.0-universal-snow-leopard.dmg installed. (That's the instance that gives me the "illegal instruction") and I also tried Github for Mac 1.7.5.  I also saw the note about the latter not being suitable for pre-Lion releases of OS X.  My real questions are -- Have others encountered this difficulty? Must I build from source?

Comment: @agentv : ok, so it's `Git` (_and not `Github for Mac`_) ok... so... i was reading the [reviews here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/reviews) on the Git 1.x.x packages and many users seem to have the same issue. One comment mentions a possible solution that is **installing the "Command Line Tools" from Xcode component download section**. (_not sure if it'll help but try it_)

Comment: @staticVoidMan Thanks. That reading reference was informative. It certainly appears that my best option is to compile from source on my machine (running Snow Leopard). The Apple developer site doesn't seem to support this OS version any longer. Can't upgrade just now, too much infrastructure already in place. But I do know a great deal more than when I started. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I presume you're all good now, but for those who come later, installing git via macports fixed it for me as per my answer below