# Git not working on snow leopard

Tags: macos, git, unix, osx-snow-leopard

Successfully installed git on my Mac (Snow Leopard 10.6.8), but cannot get any of the commands to work.  Everything I type the terminal spits out `illegal instruction`.

For example:

```
git --version

Illegal instruction
```

Note: This download was tailored for Snow Leopard as seen in the readme file they provided.  So I have no idea why this is such a pain.

```
NOTES ABOUT THIS BUILD
============

* This build targets Snow Leopard and Lion. It may work on earlier or
later versions of OS X.
```

I have tried installing `homebrew`, but that doesn't work because it can't find Xcode which I also can't get on my computer.

Anyone know why git is not working on Snow Leopard?

Comment: Where did you get git from? To install Xcode, you need the install CD.

Comment: You can dowload **Xcode** from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/ , please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10

Comment: I got git from git-scm.com which redirected me to sourceforge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git for Mac fails to launch: "illegal instruction"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892890/git-for-mac-fails-to-launch-illegal-instruction)

Comment: This [1] worked for me. I successfully installed 1.8.4.2 on 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running this on a Mac with a Core Duo processor. The git version you installed needs a Core 2 Duo.